# Error in cmdscale(dist, k = k) : NA values not allowed in 'd' when performing plot_heatmap in phyloseq

Tags: r, bioinformatics, phyloseq

I need to plot heatmaps of the taxonomic abundance of my samples. I have created my phyloseq object with no problem, but I get an error when trying to generate heatmaps:

"phyloseqin.species" is my phyloseq-class experiment-level object

```
otu_table()   OTU Table:         [ 325 taxa and 101 samples ]
sample_data() Sample Data:       [ 101 samples by 5 sample variables ]
tax_table()   Taxonomy Table:    [ 325 taxa by 7 taxonomic ranks ]
```

There are naturally some NAs in my OTU table.

When I run

```
plot_heatmap(phyloseqin.species,  sample.label="Sample", title = 'Relative abundance data - NMDS - Bray', 
+              taxa.label='Species', method = "NMDS", distance = "bray")
```

I receive this error:

```
Error in cmdscale(dist, k = k) : NA values not allowed in 'd'
In addition: Warning messages:
1: In distfun(comm, method = distance, ...) :
  you have empty rows: their dissimilarities may be meaningless in method “bray”
2: In distfun(comm, method = distance, ...) : missing values in results
```

Is this error because I do not have a tree as part of my phyloseq object?

Thank you in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

It's not because you don't have a tree - change the NAs in your OTU abundance table to 0. You can record the species as NA for a sample - but it is equally valid that you have recorded that OTU 0 times in that sample.

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.